# Is there any was to have the following structure in AG-Grid table?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

So what I'm trying to do is when a user has 2 channels let's say, the row has to be expandable. If we have more than 1 channel, the channel type must be expandable too. But the rest of the data should be visible like in the photo attached (the main group field should be the email -> the order of the columns must be as shown)

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MadXd.png)

I tried following some examples from https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-custom-group-columns/ but this way of showing the data isn't suitable for our desired design